# Flying-saucer - html to png render always 16 pixels high

Tags: java, flying-saucer

Does anyone have any experience with `flying-saucer`? I'm rendering an `xhtml` page to `png`, but the end result is always 16 pixels high. The rest gets cut off.

```
Java2DRenderer renderer = new Java2DRenderer(xHtmlFile, width); // Image height should be set automatically
BufferedImage buffImg = renderer.getImage(); // buffImg.getHeight always 16
```

The xhtml document is of course bigger.

It's basically one `div` with a few `span` elements in it, like this

```
<body>
    <div id="divThing">
        <span>text</span>
        <span>more text</span>
    </div>
<body>
```

Here's the css:

```
html
{
    color: #222;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size:20px;
}

body
{
    width:600px;
}

#divThing
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size:20px;
    word-wrap:break-word;  
    word-wrap:break-all;
    width:600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up switching to `Graphics2DRenderer` class instead, which had a method `renderToImageAutoSize`. This worked better, using `new File(File_To_Convert).toURI().toURL().toString()` argument as suggested in [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074103/flyingsaucer-renderer-setdocument-throws-stream-closed-exception)